# Riemann Stieltjes Integral with trig limit of integration!

Tags: real-analysis

$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)$$

here was my attempt;

$$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)
=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)+ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)$$
$$+\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{-\pi}{4}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)+\int_{\frac{-\pi}{4}}^{0}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)$$

pls going forward from here, how do i get rid of the modulus signs. thanks alot.

Comment: Hints:\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)+2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos2xd(\sin x)-2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos2xd(\sin x)
\end{align*}

Comment: thank u. But can u do me a favour by explaining this pls, i really want to know the techniques in case of other problems like this nature.

Comment: do u think this $-\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is the answer?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)+2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\cos2x|d(\sin x)\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos2xd(\sin x)-2\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos2xd(\sin x)\\
&=2\left\{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(1-2\sin^2x)d(\sin x)-\int_{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-2\sin^2x)d(\sin x)\right\}\\
&=\frac43\left\{-\frac1{2\sqrt2}+1-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right\}\\
&=\frac43\left\{1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\right\}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: You're wellcome